# Updating Wordpress inside a container. No FTP access

Tags: wordpress, docker, updates

I installed a Wordpress website with the `wordpress` Docker image, and then installed my themes. All works well, but when I want to update Wordpress later on, I get this message:

> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

The Wordpress container is not running an FTP server on the web root. How could I solve this problem?

**PS:** I have my web root in a data container, shared among different containers.

**PS2:** I am planning on storing several Wordpress websites in the same host. Is there also a solution that is compatible with this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key is to make sure your web server is the owner of the directory WordPress is installed in (and its sub-directories). You're seeing an error because your web server doesn't have the proper privileges to write to your directories.

I recommend running a `chown -R user:group /path/to/wordpress`, substituting the `user` and `group` with your server's info.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks! The message was quite misleading... The solution was rather easy :P

Comment: It is a confusing message. Of course, inputting FTP credentials is also a solution...but that's a pain to do every time. I think the message should be modified to explain why it needs more permissions in the first place.

Comment: wow thanks, every directory had the correct user:group, but the /var/www/html directory needed to be set to www-data:www-data (so there may be no need to use the -R flag)

Comment: I also needed to chown the linked path, i.e. apt-get installs wordpress in /usr/share/wordpress and then goes though the single index in /var/www/html.