# Not Able to Install Plugins on WordPress on Docker on Windows

Tags: wordpress, windows, docker

I have a Windows 10 Pro computer and am running WordPress on Docker locally.

Everything is working **except** when after I run `docker-compose up -d` and log into my local WordPress admin page, I try to install plugins and get the error message below from WordPress:

**To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.**

How can I configure my WordPress install (that runs locally on Docker on Windows) so that I can install WordPress plugins using the WordPress admin menu? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Wordpress inside a container. No FTP access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396506/updating-wordpress-inside-a-container-no-ftp-access)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question above because I've using Windows and not Linux or Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a work around. I just need to download WordPress plugins (like from https://wordpress.org/plugins/) and manually install them in my **plugins** directory. Now I can install plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like file directory ownership isn't properly set. I'm unfamiliar with a Windows environment, but I'd look in that direction.

As an alternative, I prefer to manage my plugins very intentionally via Composer. Using the Composer Installers package, just list the plugins you want from Packagist, and run `composer install` to install them in your plugins directory automatically.

You can see an example setup of that here:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/wp-skateboard